# The radio button value I am getting does not get values after the space

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, radio-button

```
if(len > 0) {
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){

txt += "<tr><td><h2>" + "<input type='radio'  name = 'rdb' value = " + data[i]['choice'] + "></h2></td><td><h2>"+  data[i]['choice'] + "</h2></td></tr>";

}
```

I am getting the value by doing:

```
var answerval = $('input:radio[name=rdb]:checked').val();
```

It is getting the correct value for single valued answers but for the ones that have a space, it only returns the first value before the space. I tried to do what other similar posts said about adding single quotes before the value in the radio button, however, that gives me error as it does not load up the choices. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

Comment: _but for the ones that have a space_ you mean for the radio `value` ?

Comment: Hey, pepgirl. Here's some info on writing great StackOverflow questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  This seems like a great example of when you could create a small targeted jsFiddle to show your scenario and ensure that it isn't some other code leaking in and causing the unexpected behaviour. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/ooeq1yb2/

Comment: Mind the syntax - there are lots of extra spaces and such.